# SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces on 64bit architecture on C#

Tags: c#, winapi, 32bit-64bit

I try to call Window API function *SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces* from C# on 64bits architecture.
I import function and declare additional structures.

```
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
        IntPtr deviceInfoSet,
        SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData,
        ref Guid interfaceClassGuid,
        int memberIndex,
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class SP_DEVINFO_DATA
    {
        internal int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
        internal Guid classGuid = Guid.Empty; // temp
        internal int devInst = 0; // dumy
        internal int reserved = 0;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
    internal struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
    {
        internal int cbSize;
        internal short devicePath;
    }
```

Then I call this function as follows:

```
        int index = 0;
        Guid _classGuid = Guid.Empty;
        IntPtr _deviceInfoSet = IntPtr.Zero;

        Native.SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA interfaceData = new Native.SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();

        if (!Native.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(_deviceInfoSet, null, ref _classGuid, index, interfaceData))
       {
             int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
             if (error != Native.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                 throw new Win32Exception(error);
             break;
         }
```

If runnig on *32bits* architecture then all is well.

If runnig on *64bits* architecture then *SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces* return false with last win error equal 1784. 
The reason is that in struct *interfaceData* field **cbSize has not valid value** for 64bits architecture(as int alias Int32).

From official documentation

> DeviceInterfaceData [out] A pointer to a caller-allocated buffer that
>   contains, on successful return, a completed SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
>   structure that identifies an interface that meets the search
>   parameters. The caller must set DeviceInterfaceData.cbSize to
>   sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA) before calling this function.

Trying to replace the type int(alias Int32) of the type Int64 for fields: cbSize, devInt, reserved.

**How Can I replace class Guid for 64bits architecture?**

If I try replace Guid simply of the type long:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA 
    {
        internal Int64 cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA));
        internal long  interfaceClassGuid = 0; // temp
        internal Int64 flags = 1;
        internal Int64 reserved = 0;
    }
```

With such a structure definition all works but I lose the convenience of working with a special class for guid. In the class definition Guid also used the type int so the right size will not be calculated on 64bits architecture.

Answer (score 2):

> You need to use **uint** in all fields(not **int**), and **IntPtr** in **Reserved** field.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public Guid ClassGuid;
    public uint DevInst;
    public IntPtr Reserved;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public Guid InterfaceClassGuid;
    public uint Flags;
    public IntPtr Reserved;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
{
    public uint cbSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string DevicePath;
}
```

> To set **cbSize** in code use this:

```
Win32.SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA did = new Win32.SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
did.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(did);

Win32.SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA didd = new Win32.SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA();
didd.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(didd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try setting your

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
internal struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
```

to:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
```

From what I've read, Pack = 8 for 32 bit, Pack = 1 for 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your GUID declarations; the reason `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` is failing out on 64-bit platforms is that you're not using the correct data type for the `reserved` field on each of `SP_DEVINFO_DATA` and `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA`.

The structure definitions for [`SP_DEVINFO_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552344(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552342(v=vs.85).aspx) show that the `reserved` fields are declared as `UINT_PTR`, which is a pointer type. These should be declared in your P/Invoke types as `IntPtr`.

(Also, all of your `int` fields should instead be defined as `uint`, as those fields map to the `DWORD` native type.)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal class SP_DEVINFO_DATA
{
    internal uint cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
    internal Guid classGuid;
    internal uint devInst;
    internal IntPtr reserved;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
internal struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
{
    internal uint cbSize;
    internal short devicePath;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal class SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA 
{
    internal uint cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA));
    internal Guid interfaceClassGuid;
    internal uint flags;
    internal IntPtr reserved;
}
```

Comment: Not works. Note, that the type uint is alias UInt32 therefore replacement the type int of uint is useless